# SQL Server : mapping data based on information in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to map the information in the `version` column in my SQL Server database. Right now, we have values from `v1.x.x.x.x` to `v23.x.x.x.x` and I would like something along the lines of:

```
case 
   when left(version,3) is v9. then 'v9',
   when left(version,4) is v10. then 'v10',
   when left(version,3) is between v1. and v8. then 'old'
end as 'version'
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'

Thanks!

Comment: try to put simple quotes on 'v9.' and 'v10.'

Comment: I think Between don't work with strings

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right way to do it

```
declare @version varchar(10) = 'v2.tyt'

SELECT CASE
         WHEN Substring(@version, 2, Charindex('.', @version) - 2) <= 8 THEN 'old'
         WHEN Substring(@version, 2, Charindex('.', @version) - 2) IN ( 9, 10 ) THEN 'v' + Substring(@version, 2, Charindex('.', @version)-2)
       END
```

**Note :** This always considers the format of data is something like this

```
A character|any numeric value|.|anything
```